# Conflict on document ready jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've read on several places that you can have as many `$(document).ready(function()`s as you want but I've got one at the top of my page is and in referencing one lower down in the page which is being ignored. Does anyone what could be causing it?

Top of page

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready(function($){

            $('#image1').addimagezoom({ // single image zoom
                zoomrange: [3, 10],
                magnifiersize: [300,300],
                magnifierpos: 'right',
                cursorshade: true,
                largeimage: 'hayden.jpg' //<-- No comma after last option!
            })


            $('#image2').addimagezoom() // single image zoom with default options


        })

        </script>
```

External file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // run test on initial page load
    checkSize();
    reorderPage();
    reorderBlog();
    placeTestimonials();

    // run test on resize of the window
    $(window).resize(checkSize);
});

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/columns-left.js" async="async"></script>
```

I'm using HTML 5 is that makes a difference.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: As it says at the top, can you see what is causing the second one to be  ignored.

Comment: Are you sure you linked that file correctly? Do you mind posting your whole html file for me?

Comment: And please tell us, if there are any Javascript errors on the console.

Comment: I've added the link to the question. I can't post the whole file since it's over 1,500 lines long.

Comment: No errors on the console.

Comment: @Novice `[t]he .ready() handler is passed a reference to the jQuery object that called the method. This allows the handler to use a jQuery object, for example as $, without knowing its aliased name` - from: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Ohh.. My bad then

Comment: @Jamiec But this is only needed if $.nonConflict() is used, which we do not see. And that might explain why the second $(document).ready() does not work - if a $.nonConflict() is used.

Comment: you have set async = "async" for the script tag, try removing that.. it can be because you are telling browser to download it in background and execute as and when available

Comment: Created a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/OTqLQlTfd0xGVQcCFqmp?p=preview) and it seems to be working fine. Are you sure you're external JS is getting downloaded?

Comment: @Seb it certainly *can* be used for `noConflict` and I guess thats its intention, but it works even in normal mode (https://jsfiddle.net/m4m73aud/) - jQuery *always* passes a reference to itelf in as the first argument of a ready handler.

Comment: When I delete the code at the top it get's loaded so unless the code at the top stops it being loaded.

Comment: @RichardYoung you're sure there's no errors in the JS console. Perhaps check you've loaded the code for the `addimagezoom` plugin.

Comment: Is it possible to view the page somewhere? So we can get a look at the complete code. We are more or less stumbling in the darkness here.

Comment: It does actually say in the cobsole TypeError: $ is not a function a few times.I didn't see it at first,

Comment: Is there any reason to why it conflicts? I thought you were supposed to be allowed the have as many of these on your page as you want.

Comment: I'm using code from DHTML.
       $('#main_product_image').addimagezoom({ // single image zoom
        zoomrange: [3, 10],
        magnifiersize: [300,300],
        cursorshade: true,
        largeimage: '<?=$zoom_image;?>' //<-- No comma after last option!
       })
What I'd really like to do is use an onclick to change the larger image without having to reload the page. Is there an easy way to do that?